# Idiomatic Composing of Monoids

Tags: scala

I'm continuing to work on the [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) text's exercise.

The following function, `productMonoid`, composes two monoids.

```
//@author - pchiusano
def productMonoid[A, B](A: Monoid[A], B: Monoid[B]): Monoid[(A, B)] = {
    new Monoid[(A, B)] {
        def op(x: (A,B), y: (A,B) ) = (A.op(x._1, y._1) , B.op(x._2, y._2))
        val zero = (A.zero, B.zero)
    }
}
```

Next, the integer multiplication monoid.

```
val intMultiplication = new Monoid[Int] {
    def op(a1: Int, a2: Int) = a1 * a2
    val zero = 1
}
```

Lastly, this monoid simply concatenates two strings.

```
val concatenate = new Monoid[String] {
    def op(a1: String, a2: String) = a1 + a2
    val zero = ""
}
```

Finally, I call test code to verify `productMonoid`'s functionality.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val x = (100, "hello")
    val y = (200, "world")

    val result: (Int, String) = productMonoid(intMultiplication, concatenate).op(x,y)
    println("result: " + result)
    assert(result._1 == 20000)
    assert(result._2 == "helloworld")
}
```

Is my call to `productMonoid(...)` idiomatic? Perhaps there's a cleaner way to write this code?

Answer (score 4):

Imho Monoid need to be defined as Type Class

```
trait Monoid[T] {
  def op(x: T, y: T): T
  def zero: T
}
```

And add some syntax extension for easy using:

```
trait MonoidSyntax[T] {
  def |+|(y: T): T
  def zero: T
}

implicit def toMonoidSyntax[A: Monoid](x: A) = new MonoidSyntax[A] {
  def |+|(y: A) = implicitly[Monoid[A]].op(x, y)
  def zero = implicitly[Monoid[A]].zero
}
```

Then type class instances will be defined as:

```
implicit val intMultiplication = new Monoid[Int] {
  def op(a1: Int, a2: Int) = a1 * a2
  val zero = 1
}

implicit val concatenate = new Monoid[String] {
  def op(a1: String, a2: String) = a1 + a2
  val zero = ""
}
```

and product Monoid instance:

```
//@author - pchiusano
def productMonoid[A, B](A: Monoid[A], B: Monoid[B]): Monoid[(A, B)] = {
  new Monoid[(A, B)] {
    def op(x: (A,B), y: (A,B) ) = (A.op(x._1, y._1) , B.op(x._2, y._2))
    val zero = (A.zero, B.zero)
  }
}

// instance of tuple Monoid (A, B) for any A : Monoid, B : Monoid
implicit def productM[A: Monoid, B: Monoid] =
  productMonoid(implicitly[Monoid[A]], implicitly[Monoid[B]])
```

After all your code will looks like:

```
val x = (100, "hello")
val y = (200, "world")
val result = x |+| y

println("result: " + result)
assert(result._1 == 20000)
assert(result._2 == "helloworld")
```

And finally you ***don't need to write code with monoids***. Just use [**Scalaz**](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) lib.

Comment: Even with the Scalaz library, you need to define the function `productMonoid` yourself ?